# How to show users online in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

This code only shows "1 User(s) Online" no matter how many are online. How do I fix that?

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password , $database)
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.'); 
$online = "1";
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE online = '$online'";
$data = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
$online=$row['online'];
echo '<div id="online-me" class="mydiv3"><center><span id="stats">'.$online.' User(s) Online!</span> </center></div>';
?>
```

Comment: use `select count(*) ...`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the count() of MySql
also use mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysqli_fetch_array

something like this

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password , $database)
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.'); 
$online = "1";
$query = "SELECT count(id) as 'total' FROM `users` WHERE online = '$online'";
$data = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
$online=$row['total'];
echo '<div id="online-me" class="mydiv3"><center><span id="stats">'.$online.' User(s) Online!</span> </center></div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

So with

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE online = '$online'";
```

You are getting the row where `online = 1`. Then you set `$online=$row['online'];` which just sets `$online` to `1` no matter what.

That should give you an idea of how to fix it.
Cheers! Good luck!

Comment: It gave me an idea, but I couldn't fix it. But thanks :)

Comment: @OmarAl-Ali Hey, I could possibly help if you gave me some more information about your DB structure